# How can I limit each number of occuring only once, so my secret code won't have double numbers

Tags: java

The code is supposed to return a secret code in form of colors, which it did do before the if conditions were added. The problem that occures to me, if I don't try to limit the numbers to occuring only once is as follows

Removing the if conditions from the cases makes the code "work" again but it also results in the numbers being repeated and sometimes leads to not even printing a number. Does anybody have an idea how to stop numbers from reoccuring?

```
int[] secretcode = new int[4];  
String[] farbcode = new String[4];  

public rndmcode() { // array "secretcode" wird definiert
    Arrays.fill(farbcode, "");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 && farbcode.length < 4; i++){                                                      
        //Schleife um eine Randomziffer von 1-6 zu erstellen und
        //https://trainyourprogrammer.de/java-203-programmierung-von-mastermind.html    //bis zur 4ten Stelle vom Array, da der Code 4 Zahlen bracht
        Random zufallszahl = new Random();                                      
        int rndnumber = zufallszahl.nextInt(7); //Die Zahlen 1-6 sind meine Farben, die vorrerst nur Zahlen sind
        
        switch(rndnumber) {
        case 1:
            if(Arrays.asList(farbcode).contains("Blau")){
        
            break;
            }
            else
                {farbcode[i] += "Blau";
            break;}
        case 2:
            if(Arrays.asList(farbcode).contains("Rot")) {
                break;
            
            }
        
            else
                {farbcode[i] += "Rot";
            break;}
        case 3: 
            if(Arrays.asList(farbcode).contains("Gelb")){
                break;
                }
            else{
                farbcode[i] += "Gelb";
            
            break;}
        case 4:
            if(Arrays.asList(farbcode).contains("Grün")){
                break;
                }
            else{
                farbcode[i] += "Grün";
            
            break;
            }
        case 5:
            if(Arrays.asList(farbcode).contains("Lila")){
                break;
                }
            else {farbcode[i] += "Lila";
            break;}
        
        case 6:
            if(Arrays.asList(farbcode).contains("Orange")){
                break;
                }
            else {
            farbcode[i] += "Orange";
            break;
            }
        default:
        }
    }
}
public String stringo() {

    String s = "[";
    for (String element:farbcode) {
        s+=element;
        s+=", ";
    }
    s+= "]";
    return s;
}
```

Comment: what is the usage of secretcode ? and what do you actually want to accomplish ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big switch/case with duplicate code is not a good idea. I suggest you to use an hashmap.

Also, I change the `farbcode` object into an hashmap too to check faster is the item is already added. It's better because we don't create a new array each loop iteration.

```java
int[] secretcode = new int[4];
List<String> farbcode = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<Integer, String> possibleKey = new HashMap<>();

public rndmcode() {
    // firstly define all id/keys
    possibleKey.put(0, "Blau");
    possibleKey.put(1, "Rot");
    possibleKey.put(2, "Gelb");
    possibleKey.put(3, "Grün");
    possibleKey.put(4, "Lila");
    possibleKey.put(5, "Orange");

    while (farbcode.size() < 4) { // until we don't have 4 items
        Random zufallszahl = new Random();
        int rndnumber = zufallszahl.nextInt(6); // find item between 0 and 5

        String choosed = possibleKey.get(rndnumber);
        if(choosed == null) // check if id registered
            System.out.println("Can't found key for ID: " + rndnumber);
        if(!farbcode.contains(choosed)) // don't make switch
            farbcode.add(choosed); // add item
    }
}

public String stringo() {
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ");
    farbcode.forEach(sj::add); // add all element in string
    return "[" + sj.toString() + "]"; // format string
}
```

Comment: It works up to the point of the code length, now the code sometimes only gives out 3 answers, for ex. [Blau, Gelb, Grün] or sometimes even less. my goal was to always return a 4 digit/ 4 color code and somehow that doesnt really work out together

Comment: @Crivenn I just update my answer. Is that fine now ? There is 3 items because of preventing double

Comment: It works, tyvm. Now I only need to understand how hashmaps work so I can explain how "I" did it, to my teacher hahaha <3

Comment: No problem :) An hashmap is a Key/Value object. You have an int that have a linked value, which is a string (because it's a `<Integer, String>` hashmap). Just for information: int = Integer

Answer (score 0):

The following sample code includes a method that returns an array of random unique integers

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;

public class Example {

    // Returns an array of random unique integers 
    public static int[] getArrayOfRandomUniqueIntegers(int length, int bound) {
        HashSet<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Random random = new Random();
        while (hashSet.size() < length) {
            int i = random.nextInt(bound);
            if (!hashSet.contains(i)) {
                hashSet.add(i);
            }
        }
        return hashSet.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] array = getArrayOfRandomUniqueIntegers(8, 75);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

}
```

Fabio